# How to understand another lspci tree format?

Tags: pci-express, bus

### I can understand this [lspci output](https://superuser.com/questions/1375202/how-to-understand-lspci-tree-format)

### But， I cannot understand this：

```
// lspci -tv 
-+-[0000:d7]-+-05.0  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E VT-d
 |           +-05.2  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers
 |           +-05.4  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E IOxAPIC Configuration Registers
.......
 |           +-16.4  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
 |           +-16.5  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DDRIO Registers
 |           +-17.0  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
 |           \-17.1  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DDRIO Registers
 +-[0000:ae]-+-05.0  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E VT-d
 |           +-05.2  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers
 |           +-16.5  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DDRIO Registers
......
 |           +-17.0  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
 |           \-17.1  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DDRIO Registers
 +-[0000:3a]-+-00.0-[3b-3d]----00.0-[3c-3d]----03.0-[3d]----00.0  Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X722
 |           +-05.0  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E VT-d
.....
 |           +-0d.2  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LMS Channel 2
 |           \-0d.3  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LMDP Channel 2
 +-[0000:17]-+-00.0-[18]----00.0  Device baec:baec
 |           +-02.0-[19]--+-00.0  Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
 |           |            \-00.1  Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
 |           +-05.0  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E VT-d
.....
 |           \-1e.6  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
 \-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DMI3 Registers
             +-04.0  Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
......
             +-1f.4  Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family SMBus
             \-1f.5  Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family SPI Controller
```

### This is an Intel CPU

```
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8255C CPU @ 2.50GHz
```

```
ls /sys/class/pci_bus/
0000:00  0000:02  0000:17  0000:19  0000:3b  0000:3d  0000:80  0000:ae
0000:01  0000:03  0000:18  0000:3a  0000:3c  0000:5d  0000:85  0000:d7
```

### Question

What is the origination of the buses(d7,ae,ae,17,00)?

Answer (score 1):

I found the anwer [here](https://codywu2010.wordpress.com/2015/11/29/how-modern-multi-processor-multi-root-complex-system-assigns-pci-bus-number/)

> Nowadays multi-processor systems is becoming more and more common
> especially in high performance computing.
>
> Things become interesting when you think about it from PCI Bus
> perspective: We use to model it as one PCI host bridge (root complex)
> yet now we may face the case where there are multiple PCI root
> bridges.
>
> So yes root bridge is no longer the “root” or at least not the only
> “root” and we have to move away from the simple logic of assigning Bus
> 0, Device 0, Function 0 to that device.
>
> What’s more, now they may each can connect to their own pool of memory
> chipsets how would you decide on what memory/io resource range to give
> to each of them?

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.